# android: how to save login credentials from server to phone cache

Tags: android

I have web services and I want to create a class that should takes an email and password from server after authentication in hash table, and then saves email and password in shared preferences.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` for that..Check my answer to know more about it..

Comment: I have only a class that is saving email and password in shared preferences but I have to save the server response in hash table, the server will send me a verified email and password and an authentication token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this class to call webservice in your app, i am sharing get and post both methods you can use any one as per your need.

```
public class CallService {
String url;
HttpEntity str1;
String str;
Context context;

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public CallService(String url1) {
    this.url = url1;

}

public String getResponceWithPost() {

    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,5000000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters,500000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters,true);

        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost post= new HttpPost (url);

        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

        // //////////////
        if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
               Log.e("Calling service", str);
                return str;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str;
}

public int getResponceWithGet() {
      int code = 0;

    try {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);


     code=  rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            return code;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("calling service", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("calling service", e.toString());
    }

    return code;
}}
```

this will return response from server like email password or other details.
and you can save these details in sharedpreference .
for shared preference follow this -

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

and in your activity call your url using my call service class like this-

declare your hashTable in activity like this

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
```

call this method

```
new checkForLogin().execute();
```

and your async class

```
class checkForLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String>
{

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        progress= ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this,"Authenticating !","Please Wait");

    } 
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Parse your json data here that will be in data

CallService  cl2=new CallService("your server url here");
        Log.e("login url is",""+Urls.loginurl);

        data=cl2.getResponceWithPost();

        Log.e("server response data","data = "+data);

hashtable.put(“email″, data.getString("email"));
hashtable.put(“pass″, data.getString("pass"));

        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progress.dismiss();

    }
```

i hope this ll help you.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my problem. the server will give an email, password and an authentication token and that I have to save first in hash table. can you explain how to get response in hashtable.

Comment: I have sent the request,